# sortKeys() doesn't sort Keys of Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

iam sitting here since 9am and breaking my head about this weird stuff.

Im trying to group a collection of `entries` by the year and month of `created_at`.

My code looks like this:

```php
Auth::user()
   ->entries()
   ->get()
   ->sortByDesc('created_at')
   ->groupBy(
      [   
         function($item) {
            return $item->created_at->year;
         },
         function($item) {
            return $item->created_at->month;
         },

      ]
   )
   ->sortKeysDesc()
```

But all I get is this:

```
{
    "2018": {
        "12": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "user_id": 1,
                "name": "et",
                "value": -8.6,
                "created_at": "2018-12-31 20:59:06",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-03 19:50:20"
            },
            …

        ]
    },
    "2019": {
        "1": [
            {
                "id": 42,
                "user_id": 1,
                "name": "non",
                "value": -3.5,
                "created_at": "2019-01-31 05:36:01",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-03 19:50:20"
            },
            …

        ]
    }
}
```

My target is to get the latest years at first. 2019, 2018…
As you can see, the `sortKeysDesc()` doesn't do anything at all. Yes – i tried `sortKeys()` as well -> same result.

Whats wrong with my approach?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it.

The JSON preview orders the keys ascending… well…